# Sort an excel sheet by determining the key column dynamically

Tags: excel, sorting, vba

I am new to VBA scripting and want to write a VBA script to sort an excel sheet by multiple columns.The number of columns can vary in the sheet but I need to consider two columns for sorting i.e. first & last column. E.g. here are two different excel sheet which I need to sort on basis of first & last column i.e.ID & RANK.

[image]

[image]

[sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2Vvz.jpg) 
[sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SE7g4.jpg)

I tried to dynamically find the last column using below:

```
LastColumn = Split(sht.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Cells.Address(1, 0), "$")
(0)
```

But the I'm not able to use the above variable in Range method for selecting the key.

Its throwing runtime error.

Is there any way to use the variable to select the Range or any other way to achieve this sorting.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you declare `LastColumn()`? Generally, I do `Dim lastColumn as Long` then `LastColumn = sht.cells(1,sht.columns.count).End(XlToLeft).Column`, and that returns the column number...

Comment: I just declared LastColumn as String, and its returning the last column letter not the column number.

Comment: Use the column number like @BruceWayne stated and use `Cells()` which takes a column number `Cells(RowNumber,ColumnNumber)`

Comment: I used `Cells(RowNumber,ColumnNumber)` inside the `Range()` , but again its giving runtime error. Below is my code                                 
 `Set sht = Workbooks("test_vba.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")

LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = sht.cells(1,sht.columns.count).End(XlToLeft).Column

sht.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1,LastColumn) & Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row).Sort _
Key1:=sht.Range("A:A"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
Key2:=sht.Range(Cells(1,LastColumn), Cells(LastRow,LastColumn)), Order2:=xlDescending, _
Header:=xlYes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read your comment correctly, your current code (with a few line breaks added) is

```
Set sht = Workbooks("test_vba.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = sht.cells(1,sht.columns.count).End(XlToLeft).Column 
sht.Range(Cells(1, 1), _
          Cells(1,LastColumn) & Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row).Sort _
             Key1:=sht.Range("A:A"), _
                  Order1:=xlAscending, _ 
             Key2:=sht.Range(Cells(1,LastColumn), Cells(LastRow,LastColumn)), _
                  Order2:=xlDescending, _ 
             Header:=xlYes
```

The section saying `Cells(1,LastColumn) & Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row` has an issue because you are taking the **value** from the last column on row 1 and appending the row number of the last row in column A to that - which won't give you a `Range`.

I believe you are looking for something like:

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = Workbooks("test_vba.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = sht.Cells(1, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

sht.Range(sht.Cells(1, "A"), sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Sort _
          Key1:=sht.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _ 
          Key2:=sht.Columns(LastColumn), Order2:=xlDescending, _ 
          Header:=xlYes
```